# Deploying to a Nexus OSS 2.12 Server from Maven 3

Tags: java, maven, curl, nexus

Whenever I try to use the nexus-staging-maven-plugin to deploy an artifact to my Nexus OSS 2.12 server from maven 3.05, I get an error message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonatype.plugins:nexus-staging-maven-plugin:1.6.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project myproject
Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com myproject:myproject:jar:0.0.1-20160325.164052-1 from/to snapshots (http://nexus.myproject.com/content/repositories/snapshots)
Failed to transfer file: http://nexus.myproject.com/content repositories/snapshots/com/myproject/myproject/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/myproject-0.0.1-20160325.164052-1.jar. 
Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized.
```

Now the strange thing is that I can deploy the pom using cURL with manually specified credentials:

```
curl -u deployment:deployment123 http://nexus.myproject.com/content/repositories/snapshots/com/myproject/myproject/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/myproject-0.0.1.pom --request PUT --data @pom.xml
```

I know that server credentials are configured in my `~/.m2/settings.xml` file. Here's mine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <username>deployment</username>
            <password>deployment123</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>http://nexus.myproject.com/content/repositories/central/</url>
            <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>
</settings>
```

Note that the `mirrors` section in that file is working beautifully - when I build, maven grabs my dependencies from the nexus server using the anonymous user.

The credentials that I configured in the `~/.m2/settings.xml` file are associated with a server that has the id `nexus`. This is the same server that I'm referencing in the `plugins` section of my pom.xml file:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <skip>true</skip>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.7</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <serverId>nexus</serverId>
        <nexusUrl>http://nexus.myproject.com/</nexusUrl>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The repositories to upload to are configured in the `repositories` section of my pom file:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <url>http://nexus.myproject.com/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>releases</id>
        <url>http://nexus.myproject.com/content/repositories/releases</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Finally, I can be sure that the `~/.m2/settings.xml` file is being read by running `mvn help:effective-settings`.

When I try to run the deployment from the command line, I use the command `mvn clean deploy -DskipTests=true`.

So to recap, I have a Nexus server that has the stock deployment account enabled. I can use that account to deploy an artifact to a repository from cURL, but when I try to use the same credentials to deploy from Maven, I get an HTTP 401.

Does anybody have any idea why there might be a discrepancy here?

Comment: How do you call Maven to deploy atifacts to Nexus?

Comment: Do you have a `<repositories>` section in your pom? What does that look like? What's the nexus-staging-maven-plugin for? I've never needed it before to deploy to nexus using Maven.

Comment: @khmarbaise: I run mvn clean deploy. Sorry, should have put that in the question

Comment: @jpennell added the `<repositories>` section to the question. I used the `nexus-staging-maven-plugin` because I was following some documentation on the Nexus website. That's their plugin. Are you suggesting that the standard `maven-deploy-plugin` is the way to go instead?

Comment: Have you correctly configured a staging repository are in Nexus cause if i correctly see you haven't ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been able to use `mvn clean deploy` to successfully deploy artifacts with only the following:

pom.xml

```
...

<properties>
  <nexus.url>http://mynexus.com:8081/nexus/content</nexus.url>
</properties>

<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>nexus</id>
    <url>${nexus.url}/groups/public</url>
    <snapshots>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
      <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
    </snapshots>
  </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
  <pluginRepository>
    <id>nexus</id>
    <url>${nexus.url}/groups/public</url>
  </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<distributionManagement>
  <repository>
    <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
    <id>nexus</id>
    <name>Releases</name>
    <url>${nexus.url}/repositories/releases</url>
  </repository>
  <snapshotRepository>
    <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
    <id>nexus</id>
    <name>Snapshots</name>
    <url>${nexus.url}/repositories/snapshots</url>
  </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>

...
```

settings.xml

```
...

<servers>
    <server>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <username>deployment</username>
        <password>deployment123</password>
    </server>
</servers>

...
```

I believe the important bit for deployment to nexus is the `<distributionManagement>` section.  I've never needed to declare either `maven-deploy-plugin` or `nexus-staging-maven-plugin` explicitly.

Hope that helps!

Comment: This worked perfectly. Turns out that I had a couple of issues: I was declaring a mirror of Maven Central in my settings.xml, which I didn't have to do, because Nexus does it for me, and I was using the wrong id in my repositories elements. Apparently id means different things in different contexts.

Comment: The 401 means Maven isn't sending the credentials to Nexus that have permission to publish that. Your improved pom.xml had the <id> tag in <distributionManagement> and the id matched the id in the settings.xml snippet.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the Nexus Staging Maven Plugin you need to either declare the repository to be using the staging endpoint or you need to explicitly configure the staging profile id. In your case you have configure the actual release repository instead of the staging endpoint.

Check out the documentation for the [Maven plugin](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/staging-deployment.html) and the [staging suite](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/staging.html) in general. There is also a [free video series](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/members-only/video-gallery-2/free-training/) about it that I recorded as well as a [suite of example projects](https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-book-examples).